# a question about topological property

Tags: general-topology

Let us define property *:

> A topological space $‎(X,‎\tau‎  )‎$ has property *  ‎‎, if every open cover of ‎‎$X‎$‎ has a finite subfamily whose closures cover $X$.

**question:**

> Let $X$ be a topological space with property * and $Y$ be a Hausdorff space.
>   Let $f:X ‎\longrightarrow ‎Y‎$ be a continuous function.  For every subset which has property * as $B$, does $ f‎^{-1}‎(B)$ have property *?

Comment: This will fail for _every_ infinite disjoint union of a single topological space.

Comment: Why did you stop calling the property QHC, as you did before?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the set of real numbers with the standard (or usual) topology having as a basis the collection $(a, b)$ of all the bounded open intervals where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $a < b$.

Let $\mathbb{R}_l$ denote the set of real numbers with the lower limit topology having as a basis the collection $[a, b)$ of all the bounded closed-open intervals where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $a < b$.

Then the topology of $\mathbb{R}_l$ is strictly finer than that of $\mathbb{R}$. Refer to Sec. 13 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition.

And, let $f \mathbb{R}_l \to \mathbb{R}$ be the mapping defined by
$$ f(x) = x \ \mbox{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}_l. $$

Then $f$ is continuous, because for every basic open set $(a, b)$ for $\mathbb{R}$, the inverse image of $(a, b)$ under $f$ is the same as $(a, b)$ and so is open in $\mathbb{R})_l$.

Now the closed unit interval $[0, 1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact. So it satisfies your property *.

However, 
$$ f^{-1} \big( [0, 1 ] \big) = [0, 1], $$
which fails to satisfy property *, for the open cover 
$$ \big\{ \ [0, x) \ \vert \ 0 < x < 1 \ \big\} \bigcup \big\{ [1, 2) \big\}, \tag{1} $$
for example, has no finite subfamily whose closures cover $[0, 1]$.

This we show below.

If 
$$ \big\{ \ \left[ 0, x_1 \right), \ldots, \left[ 0, x_n \right) \ \big\} \bigcup \big\{ [1, 2) \big\}  \tag{2} $$
is any finite subfamily of the open cover in (1) above, then 
$$ \left[ 0, x_1 \right) \cup \cdots \cup \left[ 0, x_n \right) \cup [1, 2) = [0, a ) \cup [1, 2), \tag{3} $$
where 
$$ a \colon= \max \left\{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \right\}. \tag{4} $$

From (1), (2), and (3) above, we note that $$ 0 < a < 1. \tag{5} $$

For each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, since the closure of $\left[ 0, x_i \right)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ equals $\left[ 0, x_i \right]$ and since the topology of $\mathbb{R}_l$ is finer than that of $\mathbb{R}$, therefore the closure of $\left[ 0, x_i \right)$ in $\mathbb{R}_l$ is contained in $\left[ 0, x_i \right]$, in fact, the closure of $\left[ 0, x_i \right)$ in $\mathbb{R}_l$ equals $\left[ 0, x_i \right)$ because the complement in $\mathbb{R}_l$ of $\left[ 0, x_i \right)$ equals 
$$ (-\infty, 0) \cup \left[ x_i, +\infty \right) = \left[ \bigcup_{x \in (-\infty, 0)} [x, 0) \right] \  \bigcup \ \left[ \bigcup_{y \in \left( x_i, +\infty \right)} \left[ x_i, y \right) \right] , $$
which being a union of basic open sets of $\mathbb{R}_l$, is open.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is correct. And as both spaces are regular, the property $(\ast)$ is equivalent to compactness (it’s H-closedness without the Hausdorff property, really). This can simplify the argument; in $\Bbb R_l$ all compact subsets are at most countable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the usual topology over $X=Y=\mathbb {R} $.

Let $f(x)=\sin x$ and $B=[0,1]$

Then clearly $B$ is a compact set and so trivially satisfies the property $*$ and $f^{-1}(B)=\mathbb{R}$ but consider an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ of the form $\{(-n,n):n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Since there is no finite subset  $A$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\mathbb{R}\subset\{[-n,n]:n\in A\}$ Hence, $\mathbb{R}$ does not satisfy $*$

Comment: beautiful answer! Can you please also check mine?